# MongoDB: Wildcard search with ObjectIDs and possibly over several collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to make a wildcard search in Mongo.

This should go over different ObjectIDs and 2 text fields

I have created an index for all fields and if I specify something for the text fields, it works.
If I specify an ID, nothing is found.

Is there a way to do this in a query?

And is there a way to do it in different collections in one step?

Thanks a lot

Comment: an index is tied to a single collection. so you cannot do multi-collection wildcard searches. for that use-case look into something like elasticsearch or lucene.

Comment: as for searching wildcard index by id, mongo documentation says this: Wildcard indexes omit the _id field by default. To include the _id field in the wildcard index, you must explicitly include it in the wildcardProjection document. See [Options for wildcard indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#createindex-method-wildcard-option) for more information.